# command 'extension.new-bloc' not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, bloc

I am a Flutter developer. I am using VS Code for bloc module generation. I tried to use the "*Bloc: New Bloc*" from the context menu, but it fails every time.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPJ9e.png]

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the extension and restarting VS Code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I tried several times, but the result was the same.
After uninstalling vscode and delete the extension folder, and reinstalled vscode and added bloc extension, but the same result occured.
Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Have you any other approach to resolve this problem?

Comment: I have VS Code 1.41.1 and I installed this [bloc extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FelixAngelov.bloc), and I don't get the error. There is a related issue posted over at the extension's Github page: [VSCode extension: command 'extension.new-bloc' not found](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/666)

Comment: Thanks, i will check the link that you prvoided me.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall and reinstall the extension. It worked for me